# Custom Error Handler Library in C++

Tags: c++, error-handling, c++17, windows

Is this code clean and optimized? When taking memory snapshots, it seems a bit high.
Anything I have done wrong or can do to optimize it?

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <Psapi.h>

// Author: https://github.com/TheRacc2
// Other Help: https://github.com/dgoguerra/, for the bytes_to_size function (modified from the "humanSize" function found in https://gist.github.com/dgoguerra/7194777)
// Repository: https://github.com/TheRacc2/error_handler/
// Report issues here: https://github.com/TheRacc2/error_handler/issues

constexpr const char* name = "Error Handler";

namespace helpers {
    // Convert bytes into readable sizes, E.G: 1024B -> 1KB, 1024000B -> 1MB
    //
    // call as such:
    // const char* sign = bytes_to_size(1024);
    const char* bytes_to_size(int bytes) {
        const char* units[] = { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB" };
        const int size = sizeof(units) / sizeof(units[0]) - 1;

        int i = 0;
        double outside_bytes = bytes;

        if (bytes > 1024)
            for (; (bytes / 1024) > 0 && i < size; i++, bytes /= 1024)
                outside_bytes = bytes / 1024;

        static char final[12];
        snprintf(final, 12, "%.01f %s", outside_bytes, units[i]);
        return final;
    }
}

namespace error_handler {
    // Use this in a "try, catch" situation, the send to developers function doesn't need to be provided.
    // 
    // call as such:
    // try {
    //     your_function_or_code();
    // } CATCH(send_log_to_developer(ex))
    #define CATCH(send_to_developers_function) \
    catch (const std::exception& ex) { \
        std::stringstream error; \
        error << ex.what(); \
        error << "\n\n"; \
        error << "Would you like to report this to the developers? Should your request be seen, this crash may be prevented."; \
        \
        if (MessageBoxA(nullptr, error.str().c_str(), name, MB_YESNO) == IDYES) { \
            send_to_developers_function; \
            MessageBoxA(nullptr, "Thank you for reporting this!", name, MB_OK); \
        } \
    }

    // Call this when something needs to go wrong, formatted like "printf". The second argument doesn't need to be provided.
    // 
    // call as such:
    // THROW("You didn't use this right! You used this like: %s", "throw()")
    // 
    // output:
    // "You didnt use this right! You used this like: throw()"
    #define THROW(text, ...) \
    error_handler::throw_ex(text, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__);

    // You shouldn't manually call this function, as you have to provide the file, function and line.
    // Use the "THROW" macro instead.
    template <typename... Args>
    void throw_ex(const char* text, const char* file, const char* function, const int& line, Args... args) {
        char message[128];
        snprintf(message, 128, text, args...);

        std::stringstream stream;
        stream << message << "\n\n";

        PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX pmc;
        K32GetProcessMemoryInfo(GetCurrentProcess(), reinterpret_cast<PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS*>(&pmc), sizeof(pmc));

        stream <<
            "{\n" <<
            "    File: \"" << file << "\",\n"
            "    Function: \"" << function << "\",\n"
            "    Line: " << line << ",\n"
            "    Memory: \"" << helpers::bytes_to_size(pmc.PrivateUsage) << "\"\n"
            "}"
        ;

        throw std::exception(stream.str().c_str());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Make `bytes_to_size()` reentrant

Since `bytes_to_size` returns a pointer to a static buffer, it is not [reentrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing)). This will be a problem if you have multiple threads throwing exceptions at the same time. There are two solutions:

1. Have `bytes_to_sign()` take a pointer to a buffer as an argument, and have it write the text into that.
2. Have it return a `std::string`.

## Avoid mixing C and C++ string formatting

It's very weird to see both `snprintf()` and `std::stringstream` used at the same time. Now you will get the worst of both worlds: type unsafety and possible truncation from `snprintf()`, and the overhead of dynamically growing memory from `std::stringstream`. Pick one and stick with it.

## Consider using `std::format`

C++20 introduced [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format), which gives you type-safe string formatting. If you want to be compatible with older versions of C++, you can use the [{fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt).

## About units

The SI prefixes are powers of 1000, if you want to make sure people are not confused, use the IEC [binary prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix), so `KiB`, `MiB`, `GiB` and so on. I would also add all the defined prefixes, so up to `YiB`.

## Consider allowing different exception types to be thrown

Your `THROW()` adds helpful information to the exception *message*, but the exception type is fixed to `std::exception`. That means that it is hard for any code that wants to catch exceptions to determine what exactly went wrong has very little information. Maybe you can add the exception type as an argument to the macro?

```
#define THROW(type, text, ...) \
    error_handler::throw_ex<type>(text, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__);

template <typename Exception, typename... Args>
void throw_ex(const char* text, ...) {
    ...
    throw Exception(stream.str().c_str());
}
```

Then it can be used like so:

```
if (value > MAX_VALUE) {
    THROW(std::out_of_range, "value %d larger than maximum %d", value, MAX_VALUE);
}
```

## C++20 will avoid the need for macros

C++20 introduces [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) which avoids the need to use macros to get the filename and line number at the place where the exception is thrown.

Comment: Thank you for this response! Actually, As I'm waiting for std::format, and would like to keep this library independent, I won't use fmt, though I thought about it. Definitely allowing custom exception types, it didn't even cross my mind! It seems when C++20 releases, this code can be condensed a lot. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

## Range Limits

Your function's description says "1024B -> 1KB", but that doesn't work, you have an off-by-one error in your implementation. This also suggests that you haven't unit-tested your code. BTW: I think you have a one-off error as well, because `size` is not the number of elements in the array, but one less. The number of elements is idiomatically computed by `(sizeof array)/(sizeof array[0])`.

Another issue with those range limits in your code is that `int` is a signed type and you're completely ignoring negative values. Additionally, you're converting the number to a floating-point type, which causes a loss of precision.

## Scaling Factor

One thing you've not gotten right is the prefixes for the different sizes. The correct ones should be `ki`, `Mi`, `Gi` etc. Alternatively, use the scaling factors of 1000, not 1024. In any case, the prefix `k` (1000) is *not* written with capital letters! More in-depth info can be found in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte#Multiple-byte_units).

## Non-Standard Exception Constructor

If you look at [std::exception docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/exception), you will not find a constructor taking a `char const*`. Your code only works because your compiler ships with a non-standard extension. Instead, use `std::runtime_error`, which has a constructor taking a string. Then, you can also drop the `.c_str()` from the expression it's initialized with.

## Namespaced Macros

...aren't. Your code

```
namespace error_handler {
    #define CATCH(send_to_developers_function) \
    ...
}
```

looks like it's isolating the macro in a namespace, but it doesn't. Macros just don't work like that, so that part is just misleading. Avoid macros in general (I guess you know that), but in this case add a check that this macro isn't already defined. Especially with common identifiers like `THROW`, collisions with other code are likely.

## Magic Numbers

This code

```
char message[128];
snprintf(message, 128, text, args...);
```

has two problems. One is that it's repeating the size of the array. Using above way to represent the size would avoid that. The other is probably some kind of cargo cult programming. Using powers of two isn't going to make your code better, faster or more correct. Why not use 100 or 200? How did you pick that number at all? This decision is what costs most time during development, so it is definitely worth documenting! In this case, it's probably just "I guess this is enough", but even that would be helpful to understand the code.

Comment: Actually, it's `kB` with a lower-case `k`, but `KiB` with an upper-case `K`. Confusing and inconsistent? Yes. But that's how it has been standardized.

Comment: Yep. Kibibyte feels unwieldy, but I'm willing to pay that price. Thanks for pointing out the `Ki` glitch.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I'll swap the unit conversions right away, as it wasn't my function to begin with, I assumed it was correct. The off_by_one error relating to size was my mistake, I'll fix it immediately. std::runtime_error seems like a better idea as well, thanks! Namespace macros was my fault, I didn't have any of my code in namespaces so I moved all of it. Magic numbers was, as you assumed, cargo cult programming. I've always used multiples of 8 for everything as force of habit.